# Jquery Next() div by ID

Tags: jquery, html

At the moment the jQuery below will only jump from `Sport` to `Entertainment`. Is there a way of getting from any `div` to the next by using one piece of code?

```
<div id="topBar">
    <span>
        <a id='slink' class='trigger' href='#Sports'>Sport</a>
        <a id='elink' class='trigger'  href='#Entertainment'>Entertainment</a >
        <a id='mlink' class='trigger' href='#Military'>Military</a>
        <a id='mocklink' class='trigger' href='#MockUp'>MockUps</a>
        <button>Next</button>
    </span>
</div>
```

```js
$("button").on('click', function() {
    $('.triggered:First').next('.triggered').show()
});
```

Comment: Are they hidden by default?

Comment: Should the previous one be hidden too? If so, you can use `:visible` every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your `.trigger` elements are all hidden by default, this should work:

```
$(".trigger:first").show();

$("button").click(function() {
    var $next = $(".trigger:visible").hide().next(".trigger");
    if (!$next.length)
        $next = $(".trigger:first");

    $next.show();
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/huH7p/)

Comment: thanks this is what i was after. So are you finding the order position by using length() and using this to find the next div? and what does ! mean, does it mean not?

Comment: @MattJameson You're correct - `!` means not. The order they cycle through in will be the order they appear in your HTML. I'm checking the length to see if there is actually a next item to show, if not it goes back to the first item.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $(this).sibling('.trigger').show();
}
```